# Setting up files to compile on any computer in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Question:
Once my code is working how should I prepare my files so that a stranger on a different computer can compile it without difficulty?

Additional Details:
I am sending a code sample to a company as part of an application so obviously an elegant solution would be better (i.e. minimise number of files required etc) and no work should be necessary by the stranger at the other end.

Although I am only using one simple library, even so I need to set include directories, include lib files, images, dll files etc so that it all compiles correctly.

If it matters, I am using Visual Studio 2015 and the simple library is SDL.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I was sure that this question would have been asked before but if it exists I just don't know the correct terminology to find it amongst the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is overly simplistic, but you might want to bound the scope of your project by deciding which computers you want to support, and build your code yourself on those platforms, in advance, just to be sure.

List the supported platforms in your release notes, including any platform-specific instructions or information (which VC++ versions, which C++ versions, which OS versions, which DLLs, directory structure, etc.).

You may have to stick some "#ifdef"s and such in your code, but only by building on a particular platform/configuration will you really know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties/props files in your VS solution which sets the paths to includes and precompiled libs, then reference the build variables in your project files.

To compile on another machine, you just need to change the values in the properties files.